# GlobalHotKeys pynput not working not reacting to function keys

Tags: python, pynput

community. I'm trying to put together a quick hotkey script in python here.
For some reason it doesn't react to function keys, meaning the expression `'<ctrl>+<F2>': function_1` doesn't work.

I was not able to find any clues in the official documentation or other examples online. Any thoughts?

Here is the script for testing.

```
from pynput import keyboard

def function_1():
    print('Function 1 activated')

def function_2():
    print('Function 2 activated')

with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
        '<ctrl>+<F2>': function_1,
        '<ctrl>+t': function_2}) as h:
    h.join()
```

Comment: Does your keyboard have special function keys, e.g. volume up, mute, etc? If your Function Lock is active, those key presses might not be recognised as `<Ctrl>+<F2>`.

Comment: I tried changing Function Lock however it didn't work. I did try this script on another laptop and it worked as expected. It seems to be a laptop issue or maybe win11 issue.. not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by moving away from *pynput* Global Hotkeys and using just *keyboard* instead. I still don't understand the nature of this issue with global hotkeys not recognizing *F1* key..

Here is the solution I used. I also added the passthrough of values with *lambda* function for each hotkey.

```
import keyboard

def func1(key):
    print("F1 is pressed with value: ", key)

def func2(key):
    print("F2 is pressed with value: ", key)

# define hotkeys
keyboard.add_hotkey('F1', lambda: func1("value1"))
keyboard.add_hotkey('F2', lambda: func2("value2"))

# run the program until 'F12' is pressed
keyboard.wait('F12')
```

Comment: Note to future readers: [`pynput.keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) and [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) are completely different Python libraries. Each has its own weakness. Thanks for the solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up a generic handler to see what events are generated:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Controller

keyboard_controller = Controller()

# The event listener will be running in this block
with keyboard.Events() as events:
    for event in events:
        if event.key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            break
        else:
            print(f"Received event {event}")
```

Running this script will then print the key press events, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will exit the script:

```
Received event Press(key='a')
Received event Release(key='a')
Received event Press(key=Key.media_volume_up)
Received event Release(key=Key.media_volume_up)
Received event Press(key=Key.f3)
Received event Release(key=Key.f3)
Received event Press(key=Key.ctrl)
Received event Press(key=Key.media_volume_up)
Received event Release(key=Key.media_volume_up)
Received event Release(key=Key.ctrl)
```

Note that this won't handle hot keys and I don't see some key presses, e.g. to get `Key.media_volume_up` events I press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.

You could potentially use `keyboard.Events()` handling to trigger your own hotkey equivalent.